# Trouble creating Javascript array which appears from an PHP array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I am having trouble to create an javascript array which appears from an php array. This is how i tried.

My PHP array called $samlet.

This is my output:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => ) [1] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => ) [2] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => 10102a ) [3] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => 10180a ) [4] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => 10210a ) [5] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => 10212a ) [6] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => 10242a ) [7] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => 10248a ) [8] => Array ( [m_field_id_8] => 10258a )
```

I want it to convert to an javascript array.

But before i do that i tried with a mockup javascript array, which works great.

```
<script>
var availableTags = [
"Test1",
"Test2",
"Test3",
"Test4",
"Test5",
];
```

now i want to use my php array instead. This is how i tried. But this does not work. Why is this happining?

```
    <?php 
    foreach($samlet as $category => $value) 
    {
    ?>
    var availableTags = [<?php echo $value['m_field_id_8']; ?>]
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: `var availableTags  = [<?php echo $value['m_field_id_8']; ?>];` You need to print or echo the value ?

Comment: And it looks like instead of `var availableTags = [1,2,3]`, you'll get `var availableTags = [1]` `var availableTags = [2]`  `var availableTags = [3]`

Comment: And then you'll do `var availableTags = [<?php echo implode(', ', $value); ?>];`

Answer (score 3):

You can use json_encode to create JSON array

```
echo 'var availableTags = ' . json_encode(array_map(function($value) {
   return $value['m_field_id_8'];
}, $samlet));
```

Comment: I tried this way, but i did not work :/ I just updated my question.

Comment: @Zaz you don't have assoc array so you don't need to use `array_values` function.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `foreach($samletas as $category => $value)`

And

```
var availableTags = [];
availableTags.push(<?php echo $value['m_field_id_8']; ?>);
```

If `$value['m_field_id_8']` is **string** type quote it like this:

```
availableTags.push("<?php echo $value['m_field_id_8']; ?>");
```

Comment: in javascript you will need to do `availableTags.push` this is only available in php. And quotes need to be inside brakets.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an array **outside of your loop**

```
var availableTags = [];
```

Then in your iteration:

```
availableTags.push(<?php echo $value['m_field_id_8']; ?>);
```

And add `as` in your `foreach`

```
foreach($samletas as $category => value);
```

Comment: I also tried this way, but i did not work :/ But i just updated my question